# Send Parameter to Controller in Routes Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I got error that says

```
Method App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Atribut\AtributDashboardController::deleteData/{id} does not exist.
```

I write my routes like this :

```
Route::group([
  'prefix' => 'atribut',
  'as' => 'atribut.'
], function () {
  
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'tabHome', 'as' => 'tabHome.'], function () {
    Route::get('', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'showTab'])->name('showTab');
    Route::post('', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'addData'])->name('addData');
    Route::get('', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'deleteData/{id}'])->name('deleteData');
    
  });
```

in the controller i also already write these :

```
public function deleteData($id)
{
    $this->inpData->deleteData($id);
    return redirect('atribut/tabHome');
}
```

i call `$this->inpData->deleteData($id)` from my models :

```
public function deleteData($id)
{
    DB::table('inp_datas')->where('id', $id)->delete();
}
```

this is the button action when delete button pressed:

```
 @forelse ($dataDisplay as $data)
  <tr>
   <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
   <td>
     <a href="{{route('frontend.atribut.tabHome.deleteData', $data->id)}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
 @empty
 @endforelse
```

why it says the method does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files), the `Route` first argument is route `name`, and in the array you have to specify class and its method.

#### Why it says the method does not exist?

In your `AttributDashboardController` you have `deleteData` method, not `deleteData/{id}`. The `deleteData/{id}` is more likely to be a route name in your case.

So for your example, delete route should look like this:

```php
Route::get('deleteData/{id}', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'deleteData'])->name('deleteData');
```

or:

```php
Route::get('{id}', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'deleteData'])->name('deleteData');
```

Laravel is smart enough to pass the `{id}` parameter to your `deleteData` method as `$id` argument.

#### HTTP DELETE

Also, if you want to make delete at this route, you will probably benefit from reading about [available router methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files), and especially [HTTP DELETE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE).